# Nested braces in twig (symfony)

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, braces

I am trying to set a data- attribute for a save button, but it doesn't like the nested braces. I'm getting an error on the "###THIS LINE" line.

```
 {% for file in payment.files %}
     <br>
     <li>
         ...
         ... etc...
         ... 
         {{ form_widget(file.save, {'attr':{'data-file-id': {{ file.id}} } }) }} ###THIS LINE

     </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I am getting is:  A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".

I guess it doesn't like the nested braces.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `{{ form_widget(file.save, {'attr':{'data-file-id': file.id } }) }}` (you are already in a twig statement  when you add `file.id` as parameter)

Comment: Hi YaatSuka, that gives this error:  An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string").

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert `file.id` into string:

```
{{ form_widget(file.save, {'attr':{'data-file-id': file.id.__toString } }) }}
```

Comment: That gives me this:   Neither the property "__toString" nor one of the methods "__toString()", "get__toString()"/"is__toString()"/"has__toString()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

Comment: Then: `{{ form_widget(file.save, {'attr':{'data-file-id': "%d"|format(file.id)} }) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Just try it:

```
{{ form_widget(file.save, {'attr':{'data-file-id': file.id } }) }}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
{{ form_widget(file.save, {'attr': {'data-file-id': file.id|string } }) }}
```

Comment: Then I just get the same error, but on **that** line

Comment: Based on the example documentation: 

{# render a widget, but add a "foo" class to it #}
{{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}